# mysql: subquery with returned many row

Tags: mysql

I have this query for load user stream in my app , is it too hard if we have 10000 matched row in 'follow' ?

```
SELECT * 
FROM post 
WHERE user_id 
IN (SELECT follow_id 
   FROM follow 
   WHERE id='$some_id') 
AND type='accepted' 
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $page , 20
```

Comment: Are you using a StoredProc or AdHoc?

Comment: whats the question? whats the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntactically your code looks correct.. I don't see any errors so then if you're talking about efficiency I would join the tables and include the second filter on the JOIN

```
SELECT p.*
FROM post p
JOIN follow f 
    ON f.follow_id = p.user_id 
   AND f.id = '$some_id'
WHERE p.type = 'accepted'
ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT $page , 20
```

MySQL handles large sets of data a lot better through a join than with an IN()...

Think of it this way.. because the IN() can have pretty much anything inside of it, MySQL has to check it with everything returned for each row... instead of checking once when you JOIN..

Comment: @aidin happy to help :) your question wasn't very descriptive just as a note for future reference when you ask a question try to explain what you want and or your desired outcome :)

Comment: @aidin if you would please mark an answer as accepted for the effort it would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

With that many returning, I have a feeling a Join might be more efficient

```
SELECT * 
FROM post p Join
     follow f On p.user_id = f.follow_id
WHERE f.id='$some_id'
AND   p.type='accepted' 
ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT $page , 20
```